# How do I disable the profile picture on the lock screen in Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I've tried changing my profile picture and now the lock screen shows a profile picture there. Setting it to the previous one doesn't help. How do I get rid of the profile picture?

Answer (score 3):

Solved by deleting `~/.face` and `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/username`.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm this works. Not sure why you were downvoted ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

> Solved by deleting ~/.face and /var/lib/AccountsService/icons/username.

This only works for a custom icon (when the `browse for more pictures` option has been used). If one of the cinnamon-settings-users' GUI stock images is used, the file path will be /usr/share/cinnamon/faces/IMAGE.JPG . The easy way to resolve this is to switch to a custom icon and then delete the two files as described above.